# Applied for a job with wrong name. How do I fix it?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

Yesterday I applied for a job via Stack Overflow, but with a wrong name.

I clicked the **apply now** button on the job description page and a pop-up opened up. The full name field was already populated with the name **Mad Man**. I wrote the cover letter and completely forgot to change the name before submitting my application.

I just saw my mistake today that I had sent my application by this name: **Mad Man**.

Is there a way I can fix this? I can't even write a message to the employer until they respond to me.

Comment: Thank you! This already made my day...

Comment: Why was the field populated with that name - was it your SO/SE user name?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't know why. My SO username never was Mad Man. Even now if I apply for a job, the name field in that popup is still filled with that name.

Comment: What? That seems weird. You're not on a shared computer or something?

Comment: rather than editing your post with updates, you should leave it as an answer as it seems like a valid answer to this question

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for suggesting that. Done!

Comment: I suggest you stop being so mad, man.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got an email from SO (after I contacted them about my problem as [Magisch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5389107/magisch) suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326779/1925257)). Here's part of the email:

> ... sorry however once an application has been submitted to an employer it cannot be amended as they are being reviewed.

Answer (score 20):

I looked into where the name 'Mad Man' came from and it definitely didn't come from any data we have on SO/SE. The only possibility is that your browser auto-completed the box with a name you (or somebody using your computer) previously entered elsewhere.

This is clearly undesirable behaviour and I've changed the inputs on that form to prevent them auto-completing.

Comment: I signed in from a different browser this time which, BTW, I never use. Surprisingly, the *Full Name* field is still pre-populated by *'Mad Man'*. Although, the *Email* and *Location* fields are filled in correct.

Comment: Yes, in that case it's by design - it gets pre-populated with the details from your last application which obviously used 'Mad Man'. If you update it on your next application it'll be used in future.

Comment: In the mean time, I hate it when forms don't auto complete for stuff like name...

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat you'd only need to do this the first time you hit that form. Subsequent to that the form is populated with the values you used for your last application.

Comment: What? You disabled a user friendly feature just because someone uses weird names to submit forms and is stupid enough to not use a private mode like incognito when they're doing so, as well as ignorant to proof read a job application before sending? Why punish all the sane people? I don't like this.

Comment: You should just tell the guy that the name came from the computer and browser settings he is using, and that SE is not responsible for his mistake. And maybe you can give some advice how to avoid such situations. Disabling a user friendly feature for 1 guys mistake? No no.

Comment: @TJ this isn't the first time this has happened. How much effort is it to fill in two fields, both of which are populated with information we already have for you if you created a CV / developer story or applied to a job before. We're minimising the risk of the browser populating a field that should be something you consciously entered in the context of sending a job application...

Answer (score 4):

Just re-apply for the job using your correct name. It's unlikely that any explanation will suffice

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to wait until an employee responds here, you can attempt to use the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link that can be found on every page at the bottom and explain your problem. Select "I need help with Careers/Jobs" in the topic selection, too.

Comment: Thanks. I contacted SO but in reply I got a mail saying, *"The staff is currently gone for the day..."*.

Comment: Okay. I got an email from SO saying that applications can't be changed once submitted. But it was worth trying, though. Thanks.

Comment: This was better off as a comment, I think.