# How to reapply on Stack Overflow with new resume?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I applied for a job and I sent my old resume by mistake.

I want to reapply and send my new resume on Stack Overflow. Is this possible and how can I do this?

Comment: Related, from someone trying to correct a field they submitted: ["... sorry however once an application has been submitted to an employer it cannot be amended as they are being reviewed."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326811/7795130) Hopefully that's not the end of the story in your case though.